# Tornado @gen.coroutine closes long polling connection

Tags: python, tornado, long-polling

Hi i have a problem with Tornado framework implementing long polling.
The post method of my requesthandler is decorated with both `@asynchronous` and `@gen.coroutine`. When i leave it hanging for a callback to be called in order to write back to the client, the connection is immediately closed. I saw that this is related to the use of `@gen.coroutine` that automatically calls `self.finish()` when all futures have been yielded.
I need this decorator because i'm using Mongo Motor.
A short example below:

```
@web.asynchronous
@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
  #mongo Motor yielding code  
  notifications.register_callback(self.on_message)
```

Notifications is a global object that keeps an array of callbacks and calls them upon receiveing a message from outside.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`@gen.engine`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.engine) instead of `@gen.coroutine` if you want to use `yield` to call coroutines, but not have `self.finish()` called automatically at the end of the handler. There's a comment in the code of the `@web.asynchronous` decorator that notes this:

```
# If @asynchronous is used with @gen.coroutine, (but
# not @gen.engine), we can automatically finish the
# request when the future resolves.  Additionally,
# the Future will swallow any exceptions so we need
# to throw them back out to the stack context to finish
# the request.
```

So, if `@asynchronous` is used with `@gen.coroutine`, it will automatically call `self.finish`, but it will skip it if used with `@gen.engine`.

Comment: @Peterdeka Yes, you should be able to use the same syntax to call into `motor`.